# KEA DHCP and Stork on 22.04

Tags: apt, server, dhcp

Trying to replace the EndOfLife isc-dhcp-server with KEA. Its a bit tricky, because the package description (command apt/apt-get) in not well documented. At least I found the package name under Ubuntu is kea-dhcp4, not isc-kea-dhcp-server.
Because of using the KEA HA feature, i tried to install Storck - the Web GUI to manage my DHCP servers.
What is the real package name under ubuntu 22.04 ?

Thx

Comment: It seems only up to Ubuntu 20.4 is officially supported. You should probably raise an issue on their [Gitlab page](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/stork) about support for Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Thx. I'm not really familiar with package deployment. But, if i'm right, I can add an older package source (20.04) to the apt sources? I added "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal main multiverse universe

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-security main multiverse universe

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-backports main multiverse universe

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-updates main multiverse universe" but didnt work.

Comment: Definitely DON'T do that - adding old sources can give all kinds of dependency problems. You should contact the developer and make them package a version for Ubuntu 22.04 - or else you should compile from source yourself.

Comment: The existing Stork packages are here: https://cloudsmith.io/~isc/repos/stork/groups/ But it will require some amount of manual work - to check valid dependencies etc. I can't guarantee anything!

Comment: Luckily, i find an older Rasperry Pi 3 and install ubuntu 20.04. But ... the same, curl  from cloud smith, then apt install, apt search for isc-stork-server failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw this, the package on ubuntu is isc-stork-server for the server side, and isc-stork-agent for the kea servers.  I am running a Kea HA setup, with 2 pairs of dhcp servers using the mysql backend (also HA) and it's been very reliable.  I use stork some for management, but it's mostly for statistics and monitoring.  I built a custom .Net Core app that does all of the server management and configuration, as well as NAC/802.1x for the system.  It's very stable and works real well.